# Use if not exist command with a broad directory search

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I'm kind of trying to combine two different things
I'm aware that  `dir/s C:\chrome.exe` exists to just search my computer to see if chrome is installed however I'm also trying to add something like

```
IF NOT EXIST dir/s C:\chrome.exe \\public\SoftwareDist\googlechrome.bat
```

how would I do this?

Comment: Use conditional execution.  `dir /b /s chrome.exe || googlechrome.bat`  The double pipe executes when the previous command was not successful.

Comment: Just bear in mind that the `Dir` command is performing only a listing of files named `chrome.exe` within the current tree; it doesn't care or check whether that file is installed as a program. If `Chrome` is installed, just entering `Chrome` or `Start Chrome` should be sufficient to run it. Given that, you may be able to use, `Chrome 2>Nul||Call \\public\SoftwareDist\googlechrome`. If the registry entries aren't in place to run `Chrome` using just its name, there are better ways of determining whether it has been installed than searching all filenames in a tree for a known executable name.

Answer (score 1):

when chrome is correctly installed, it appears in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe` so
you can use the returned error of the `reg query` command to decide and proceed only if not installed. Something like this:

```
@echo off
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe" >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto notfound
rem Chrome is installed, exit
goto :eof

:notfound
rem chrome not installed, proceed
call \\public\SoftwareDist\googlechrome.bat
....
```

Comment: @TomBernardi Yes, that is the right approach to find out if Google Chrome is installed on a Windows PC according to [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration) and not searching around on hard disk if by chance a file (or directory) with name `chrome.exe` could be found somewhere.